# Which line of code I have to write for Localization?

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, localizable.strings

code 1 :

```
cell.textLabel.text = LocalizedString(@"nice title");
```

code 2 :

```
cell.textLabel.text = LocalizedString(@"nice title",nil);
```

What is the difference between them ?

which one is correct and can be used ?

Comment: What does your test result say?

Comment: I did not understand the difference between them. I am confusing. Somewhere in app, changing the language and somewhere it is not showing, that's what I have a doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write it like this

```
cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"nicetitle",@"comment goes here");
```

[image]

Comment: is it comment field is required ? what if add I add any comment in it ?

Comment: no it's not required actually if the key doesn't exists in localization file it will replace the text value with the key

Comment: ohh..got it @Sh_Khan. Thank you.

Comment: Image explains everything... Wish Mallik would have read this before...